# Is it possible to render a region in a menu template?

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

In my Drupal 8 theme I have a template called __menu.html.twig which gets called in my page.html.twig

I am trying to render a region within the __menu.html.twig where I can place blocks.

I have rendered the region within my theme.info. How can I declare the region in __menu.html.twig?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question as you are stating that you want to render a region in the menu template. You can't do this in the traditional sense but you can use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) to render blocks pretty much in any template assuming you have the right context.

See their help pages for good documentation on how to do this.

- [Twig Tweak Cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak-2x/cheat-sheet)
- [Rendering blocks with Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak)

As an example, to render a block in any template, you'd write something like this:

```
{{ drupal_block('plugin_id', {label: 'Example'|t, some_setting: 'example', setting_array: {value: value}}) }}
```

You can also render views and full entities which comes in handy as well, for example:

```
{{ drupal_entity('block_content', 1) }}
```

In general, Twig tweak is a super handy module that we use pretty much on most D8/D9 projects.